# In Ruby how can I add a nested array to an array without creating an additional layer of nesting?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm trying to do something roughly analogous to this

```
collection = []
pair_one = [[:ae1,:be1],[:ae2,:be2]]
collection << pair_one
pair_two = [[:ae3,:be3],[:ae4,:be4]]
collection << pair_two
```

The problem is that `collection` is this:

```
[[[:ae1, :be1], [:ae2, :be2]], [[:ae3, :be3], [:ae4, :be4]]]
```

and I want it to be this:

```
[[:ae1, :be1], [:ae2, :be2], [:ae3, :be3], [:ae4, :be4]]
```

What method should I use instead of `<<`?

Basically I want to add the *contents* of `pair_one` and `pair_two` to `collection`, rather than the arrays themselves.  What array method is escaping my memory?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your "I want it to be this" is not a valid Ruby array. The first example is exactly what you should be getting back from your code.

Comment: whoops... just a sec and I'll fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-concat), [`+=`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-2B) or [`|=`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-7C)

・ `concat` to avoid unnecessary object creation.
・ `|=` to eliminate duplicates.

```
collection = []
#=> []
pair_one = [[:ae1,:be1],[:ae2,:be2]]
collection += pair_one
#=> [[:ae1, :be1], [:ae2, :be2]]
pair_two = [[:ae3,:be3],[:ae4,:be4]]
collection += pair_two
#=> [[:ae1, :be1], [:ae2, :be2], [:ae3, :be3], [:ae4, :be4]]
```

Comment: @iconoclast: But +1 to you for asking such a nice question `^_^`

Comment: There's also [`Array#concat`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-concat), which creates fewer objects because it modifies the original array in place.

Comment: @x1a4: I think `+=` is overloaded to do exactly the same thing (modify the original array in place), so there should be no difference performance-wise.

Comment: @NiklasB. [The docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-2B) are saying `+` returns a new array. If you are aware otherwise, I'd like to find that documentation.

Comment: @x1a4: I was talking about `+=`, not `+`. I thought that `+=` is overloaded like in Python, but that doesn't seem to be the case, as a quick test in IRB shows

Comment: @NiklasB. The ruby compiler just replace all `a += b` by `a = a + b`.

Comment: @oldergod: Yeah, but I thought you could overload the `+=` operator as you can in Python. Turns out you can't